# Which field shows the object name in items to approve list?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Which field shows the type or name of the object in the `items to approve` list.

[image]

I could not find anything on the `ProcessInstanceWorkitem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both SObjects: ProcessInstance and ProcessInstanceHistory contain field `targetObjectId`. Using this ID field, you can derive the SObject name:

```
String sObjectName = theIdField.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
```

This is documented here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_id.htm?SearchType=Stem  (scroll down a bit to see the example)